# syncing mysql tables using JPA

Tags: jpa

i have one spring application which is inserting/accessing data from MYSQL using JPA. 
following are two table in mysql :

1. user  (columns:  username and manager name)
2. service ( columns:  service name and user name (FK to user table)

These table are getting update by two separate jobs (ruby script) 
which are running every 5 min and getting data from LDAP server (for user) and service name (from XML file checkin in repo) and then calling REST API of my spring application for adding data using JPA.

my problem is, i want to delete entry for user who has left from organization.
currently all data is adding in mysql but no deletion due to this lots of steal data is present.

i am thinking of below:;

1. read data from LDAP server
2. put data in temporary table
3. take a diff between temporary table and persistent table, get the diff
4. update user and service table with diff.

is it possible to get step 2,3 and 4 using JPA?
or could you please suggest if there any better option to sync my tables with latest data without steal data.

Comment: You can also do step 1 using DataNucleus JPA, fwiw. Then it could be a case of detaching from the LDAP EMF and attaching to an RDBMS EMF.

Comment: the step 1 is done and data is getting imported in mysql. i am looking the other steps how the tables have latest data without the steal one. I think this is a generic issue how to make tables always sync with external data. where data is imported by other source in table.my problem is the old data is in mysql tables and new data is coming from external sources ,so i basically want whenever the new data for example user_name imported and replace the old data, i should able to delete stale data (user_name which is not present in new data). Is there any way i can do step 2,3, and 4 using JPA?